# Public Facing High-Traffic Silverlight Sites

Tags: .net, silverlight

What sites do you know of that are using Silverlight? This information will help us to decide when to adopt the Silverlight platform.

*The sites should be public-facing and be considered high-traffic.* (at least 300,000 hits per month).

We are a Microsoft shop and Silverlight is based on .NET, so that is very attractive to us. But my research has turned up only a couple of high-traffic public websites that are using Silverlight: The NBC Olympics website and the Major League Baseball site (which is moving to Flash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following public-facing sites use Silverlight.  I don't have any data to show that they meet your "high-volume" criteria, although I'm sure that NCAA, NBC Olympics, and Microsoft Downloads easily qualify.

- **Hard Rock Memorabilia** (http://memorabilia.hardrock.com/)
- **NCAA March Madness** (http://mmod.ncaa.com/)
- **NBC 2010 Olympics** (http://www.nbcolympics.com)
- **Netflix** (http://www.netflix.com)
- **Smooth HD** (http://www.smoothhd.com/)
- **Renault Megane** (http://www.new-megane.renault.co.uk)
- **Microsoft Download Center** (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/default.aspx)

For even more, check out the Silverlight Showcase at http://silverlight.net/showcase/.

Answer (score 2):

I believe netflix uses silverlight as an option. I'm not a subscriber so I can't confirm.

Comment: Netflix has moved to Silverlight - they previously used an ActiveX object which made "Watch Now" IE only.

Comment: I can confirm for you. They switched to silverlight in October 2008, as this gave them mac support.

Answer (score 1):

The only other site I could find was CBSSports.com when they used Silverlight to cover the NCAA tournament.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that Major League Baseball switched from Sliverlight to Flash is that a lot of people watch baseball at work (?!?). They had trouble getting Silverlight installed because PCs in a corporate environment are typically locked down and users can't install software on them. But almost all PCs have Flash installed. Article here:

> http://news.zdnet.com/2100-9595_22-285784.html

Answer (score 0):

NBC used it for the Olymipcs.

Answer (score 0):

Setanta sports have launched a interactive video site based on Silverlight.  Can't judge on traffic as it only went live this week - but I'd expect it to become pretty high volume

http://setanta-i.com/

Answer (score 0):

Another cool silverlight site www.windows4all.com